# How do I send request without await?

Tags: http, rust, async-await, reqwest

I am using reqwest, and am trying to send a request every 97 ms. But, I do not want to have to wait for the last request to happen or for it to be read.

I just want a request to send every 97 ms and to be sending the output at all times to stdout.

my (current) code is like this: (`keys` is an array with api keys)

```
    loop {
    for i in keys.iter() {
        let url = format!("https://api.[insertsite].com/blahblah&apiKey={}", i);
        let res = client
            .get(url)
            .send()
            .await?
            .text()
            .await?;

        sleep(Duration::from_millis(97)).await;

        println!("{:?}", res);
        }
}
```

If I remove the awaits the compiler tells me that `` error[E0599]: no method named `text` found for opaque type `impl std::future::Future` in the current scope ``.

TL;DR: I want to send a get request every 97 ms, regardless of any response. If/when there is a response pipe that response to stdout.

EDIT:

I tried to use threads, but I do not really know how to. Here is what I came up with:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let keys = ["key", "key", "key"];
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
        .build()?;
    for i in keys.iter() {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let url = format!("https://api[insertsite].com/blahblah&apiKey={}", i);
            let res = client
                .get(url)
                .send()
                .await
                .text()
                .await;
             println!("{:?}", res);
             });
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(97)).await;
}
}
```

I get this error when trying to run:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `text` found for enum `std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:22:18
   |
22 |                 .text()
   |                  ^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already discovered that `tokio::spawn` is the correct tool for this task, since you essentially want to use some async code in a "fire-and-forget" way, without waiting for it in the main program flow. You just need a little adjustments to your code.

First, for the error you're quoting - it is due to the fact that you have to somehow handle the possible error during the request. You can simply add question marks after each `await` returning `Result`, but then you run into the following:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `Try`)
  --> src/main.rs:11:23
   |
9  |           tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  _________________________________-
10 | |             let url = format!("https://api[insertsite].com/blahblah&apiKey={}", i);
11 | |             let res = client.get(url).send().await?.text().await?;
   | |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async block that returns `()`
12 | |             println!("{:?}", res);
13 | |         });
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `Try` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: required by `from_error`
```

The "this function" bit might be a little misleading, since the rest of the error is talking about "async block", but the gist is simple: if you use question mark to bubble error out of somewhere, the happy path must return `Result`, too. Well, let's simply add `Ok(())` to the end of async block, and here's the next error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:11:51
   |
11 |             let res = client.get(url).send().await?.text().await?;
   |                                                   ^ cannot infer type of error for `?` operator
   |
   = note: `?` implicitly converts the error value into a type implementing `From<reqwest::Error>`
```

That's expected, too - in the ordinary function return type would be provided by its signature, but in the async block that's not an option. We can, however, use the turbofish:

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
    // snip
    Ok::<_, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>(())
});
```

Note that we need both `Send` and `Sync`: the former is necessary for the resulting error to be able to cross the async block boundary, and the latter - because `Box<dyn Error + Send>` [can't be created with `From/Into` conversion from other errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E).

---

Now, we're left with two more compile errors, independent of the ones before:

```
error[E0597]: `keys` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:14
   |
8  |     for i in keys.iter() {
   |              ^^^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              cast requires that `keys` is borrowed for `'static`
...
18 | }
   | - `keys` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `client`
  --> src/main.rs:9:33
   |
7  |       let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
   |           ------ move occurs because `client` has type `reqwest::Client`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
8  |       for i in keys.iter() {
9  |           tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  _________________________________^
10 | |             let url = format!("https://api[insertsite].com/blahblah&apiKey={}", i);
11 | |             let res = client.get(url).send().await?.text().await?;
   | |                       ------ use occurs due to use in generator
12 | |             println!("{:?}", res);
13 | |             Ok::<_, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>(())
14 | |         });
   | |_________^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

The first of them can be fixed in three possible ways:

- use `Vec` insted of array and drop the `.iter()`,
- use `std::array::IntoIter`,
- use `.iter().copied()`.
  In each case, we'll get `&'static str`, which can be passed into the async block.

The second is even easier: we can simply do `let client = client.clone();` at the start of each iteration, before `tokio::spawn`. This is cheap, since [`Client` uses `Arc` internally](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.3/reqwest/struct.Client.html).

Here's the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef6885f5fa87b81c10b190d503202bf3), with all the changes described above.

---

Finally, here's the version which I'd personally recommend to base your code on, since it not only compiles, but additionally does not swallow the errors which can arise on request:

```
use core::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let keys = ["key", "key", "key"];
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;

    for i in std::array::IntoIter::new(keys) {
        let client = client.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let url = format!("https://api[insertsite].com/blahblah&apiKey={}", i);
            // moved actual request into inner block...
            match async move {
                let res = client.get(url).send().await?.text().await?;
                // ...returning Result with explicit error type,
                // so that the wholeinner async block is treated as "try"-block...
                Ok::<_, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>(res)
            }
            .await
            {
                // ...and matching on the result, to have either text or error
                // (here it'll always be error, due to invalid URL)
                Ok(res) => println!("{:?}", res),
                Err(er) => println!("{}", er),
            }
        });
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(97)).await;
    }

    // just to wait for responses
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd8d2d404fd74b4d7133fb82638d4611)